# problem with saving password to .rdp file

Tags: asp.net

I created ASP.Net page which create .rdp file and then open it as below:

```
 public static void Rdc(String server, String UserName, String password, out String filename)
{
    String ss= Environment.UserName;
    filename = @"c:\temp.rdp";
    if(File.Exists(filename))
        File.Delete(filename);
    if (!File.Exists(filename))
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filename))

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("screen mode id:i:2");
            sw.WriteLine("desktopwidth:i:1440");
            sw.WriteLine("desktopheight:i:900");
            sw.WriteLine("session bpp:i:32");
            sw.WriteLine("winposstr:s:0,1,4,12,1440,864");
            sw.WriteLine("compression:i:1");
            sw.WriteLine("keyboardhook:i:2");
            sw.WriteLine("administrative session:i:1");
            sw.WriteLine("displayconnectionbar:i:1");
            sw.WriteLine("disable wallpaper:i:1");
            sw.WriteLine("disable full window drag:i:1");
            sw.WriteLine("allow desktop composition:i:0");
            sw.WriteLine("allow font smoothing:i:0");
            sw.WriteLine("disable menu anims:i:1");
            sw.WriteLine("disable themes:i:0");
            sw.WriteLine("disable cursor setting:i:0");
            sw.WriteLine("bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1");
            sw.WriteLine("full address:s:" + server);
            sw.WriteLine("username:s:" + UserName);
            sw.WriteLine("password 51:b:" + rdpEncrypt(password));                
            sw.WriteLine("audiomode:i:0");
            sw.WriteLine("redirectprinters:i:1");
            sw.WriteLine("redirectcomports:i:0");
            sw.WriteLine("redirectsmartcards:i:1");
            sw.WriteLine("redirectclipboard:i:1");
            sw.WriteLine("redirectposdevices:i:0");
            sw.WriteLine("autoreconnection enabled:i:1");
            sw.WriteLine("authentication level:i:0");
            sw.WriteLine("prompt for credentials:i:0");
            sw.WriteLine("negotiate security layer:i:1");
            sw.WriteLine("remoteapplicationmode:i:0");
        }

    }
}
```

and then call it from the web page :

```
  public static Boolean openrdp(string path)
{
    // Get the physical Path of the file 
    string filepath = path;

    // Create New instance of FileInfo class to get the properties of the file being downloaded 
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filepath);

    // Checking if file exists 
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        // Clear the content of the response 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();

        // LINE1: Add the file name and attachment, which will force the open/cance/save dialog to show, to the header 
        //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name); 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + file.Name);


        // Add the file size into the response header 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

        // Set the ContentType 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(file.Extension.ToLower());

        // Write the file into the response (TransmitFile is for ASP.NET 2.0. In ASP.NET 1.1 you have to use WriteFile instead) 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);

        // End the response 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
public static string ReturnExtension(string fileExtension)
{
    switch (fileExtension)
    {
        case ".htm":
        case ".html":
        case ".log":
            return "text/HTML";
        case ".txt":
            return "text/plain";
        case ".docx":
            return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        case ".doc":
            return "application/msword";
        case ".tiff":
        case ".tif":
            return "image/tiff";
        case ".asf":
            return "video/x-ms-asf";
        case ".avi":
            return "video/avi";
        case ".zip":
            return "application/zip";
        case ".xls":
        case ".csv":
            return "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        case ".gif":
            return "image/gif";
        case ".jpg":
        case "jpeg":
            return "image/jpeg";
        case ".bmp":
            return "image/bmp";
        case ".wav":
            return "audio/wav";
        case ".mp3":
            return "audio/mpeg3";
        case ".mpg":
        case "mpeg":
            return "video/mpeg";
        case ".rtf":
            return "application/rtf";
        case ".asp":
            return "text/asp";
        case ".pdf":
            return "application/pdf";
        case ".fdf":
            return "application/vnd.fdf";
        case ".ppt":
            return "application/mspowerpoint";
        case ".dwg":
            return "image/vnd.dwg";
        case ".msg":
            return "application/msoutlook";
        case ".xml":
        case ".sdxl":
            return "application/xml";
        case ".xdp":
            return "application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml";
        case ".rdp":
            return "application/x-rdp";
        default:
            return "application/octet-stream";
    }

}
```

the problem id that remote connection opened but with user name only without password.
Note: i encypt the password in .rdp file

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the passwords in the RDP file are encrypted by the user who saves it (i.e. the web application pool user). And decrypted on the fly when opened.

So if another user tries to open it (i.e. the user downloading the file), then the encrypted password cannot be read.

---

EDIT

Looking at this [article about generating RDP files](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/18/how-rdp-passwords-are-encrypted/)

It looks as though the CryptProtectData function is used to encrypt the information. According to [MSDN about CyptProtectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261.aspx) this can only be decrypted by the person with the same user credentials and typically on the same computer the encryption was performed. The msdn article does mention the use of roaming profiles to decrypt on other computers.

So perhaps you can authenticate your ASP.net with Active Directory and impersonate the user whilst doing the encryption and then they might be able to decrypt on their local machine.

Another thing I have seen is that terminal services on "Juniper" launches what appears to be remote desktop and logs you in automatically. So perhaps researching this may give you another option. You may be able to get more detail about Juniper on serverfault.com

Comment: Hi @Ragaei Mahmoud i've done some digging and added more detail to my answer. Hope it helps.