# calling CryptProtectData function from javascript or vbscript

Tags: javascript, com, vbscript, rdp

I am creating a site where users can save different credentials and while logging to a VM, they can simply choose to log in using a particular credential. Therefore, I have to generate a rdp file containing the username/password selected. That is fine, but the problem is the password in a rdp file needs to be encrypted using CryptProtectData function found in crypt32.dll. This can be done without a sweat but the problem is the file can be decrypted only on that computer on which it was created.

Therefore, even if I create a rdp file on the fly and send it to the clients, they are not able to open it as it was not created on their machine. So, I have to somehow encrypt the password from the client side and generate the rdp file. But I can't get to know how do I call functions of COM objects from the client side.

Please help.

Comment: can you explain a little more about your setup? E.g. can you install software on the user's machine? Do they all have their own passwords or are they sharing them? Why do they connect to the same machines with different usernames?

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem with saving password to .rdp file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594744/problem-with-saving-password-to-rdp-file)

Comment: Hi Ben,
The thing is I have a website which allows users to log on to different virtual machines. Now they need different credentials for the same machine because, sometimes they need to login as admin, sometimes as user etc.

Comment: And no, this is not a duplicate because I want to create the rdp file from the client side, the link says to create it from the server side.

Comment: Can you install software on the user's machine? What is the "etc"? Is there more than just admin and one user they have to login as?

Comment: No I can't install software on the user's machine. That would defeat the purpose of creating a website, because each time the user opens the site on a different machine, he/she needs the software installed there too. 

There can be a lot of credentials-
domain admin, domain user, local admin, local user.

Comment: you can't call CryptProtectData from within a browser. Updated my answer with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to not do this. Instead, generate the RDP file with no password, and train the users to check the box to save the credentials on their machine.

Set `prompt for credentials:i:0`, and the user will be prompted for username and password on the first occasion. They will have the opportunity to check a box to save the credentials, and will not be asked again on subsequent occasions.

Note that you can't call CryptProtectData from within a browser. If you cannot install software on the user's machine, or have the user do it, you cannot do this at all.

There used to be a capability to do this but it was removed in XPSP2 and 2003SP1.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382919(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: No, see that cannot be a solution because this is a website. So, users will log in from different machines.
Moreover, they need to log in the same machine with different credentials. Saving the credentials means they'll have to change the username again when they have to change it.